# Get the text value of the button that was clicked

Tags: c#, winforms, events

I am trying to get the text value from a button that was clicked. In my head, it looks something like this:

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string s =  thisbutton.text
}
```

Answer (score 48, accepted):

The object which fired the event is `sender`, so:

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string s = (sender as Button).Text;
}
```

Comment: When I use this, i get the error "Button" does not contain the definition for Text, and intellisense only gives me TextInput as something similar.

Comment: @DumitruDaniel When using WPF you have to use `(sender as Button).Content`. I guess `.Text` relates to Windows Forms.

Answer (score 5):

Just cast the sender Object to a Button Object and access the text attribute :

```
protected void btn_Click (object sender, EventArgs e){
   Button btn = sender as Button;
   string s= btn.Text
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Should be like this:

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  string s =  this.button2.Text;
}
```

Comment: `this.button2.Text;` will actually get text from button 2 so the text will be always same

Comment: i assume that this event is shared for multiple buttons. dont attention to method name `button2_Click`.

Comment: I really wanted to access the button dynamicly so i can use the same code. See the accepted answer above. I should have been more clear i guess.

Answer (score 1):

In every build in event handler there are 2 parameters `sender` and `e`.`Sender` takes reference to that object which fires the event.The second parameter `e` holds some information about the event(such as the location of pointer and other of this kind)
You need only bring it to Button type and get what information you want

Answer (score 0):

try and apply this example in your button event

```
private void button_click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   var getValue = ((Button)sender).Text; //this will get the value of the text using sender
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This was asked some time ago and the platform in my case may be a little different to what the OP used but I arrived at the same question for GTK.

I am developing in Xamarin / Visual Studio in OSX using GTK2+, and for me the original accepted answer is close, but yields an error that `.Text` doesn't exist. In my case, it needs to be `Label`. This works for me:

```
protected void Button_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Button btn = sender as Button;

    lblWhichButton.Text = btn.Label;
    if (btn.Label == "<<<" )
        i--;
    else
        i++;
    lblCounter.Text = "" + i;
}
```